# Ошибка при установке python библиотеки face-recognition

Tags: python

Когда я запустил установку:

> pip install face-recognition

Как исправить ошибку?

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-toiy8za9'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\
  Complete output (62 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\setup.py:129: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
    if LooseVersion(cmake_version) < '3.1.0':
  Building extension for Python 3.8.9 (tags/v3.8.9:a743f81, Apr  6 2021, 14:02:34) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!




  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\setup.py", line 134, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib, face-recognition
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rat9ehz5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\
    Complete output (66 lines):
    running install
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\setup.py:129: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
      if LooseVersion(cmake_version) < '3.1.0':
    Building extension for Python 3.8.9 (tags/v3.8.9:a743f81, Apr  6 2021, 14:02:34) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


      You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
      are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
      that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
      development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!




    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        return run_commands(dist)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 68, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install.py", line 662, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\setup.py", line 134, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8qeqe9kr\\dlib_415b890b2c46490490cac841780b14d7\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rat9ehz5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам ошибка говорит что нужно сделать прямым текстом:
"Для сборки дополнения python на windows необходимо использовать Visual Studio.  Если вы получаете эту ошибку, это означает, что вы не установили Visual C++.  Обратите внимание что существует много разновидностей Visual Studio, например Visual Studio для C# разработки.  Вам необходимо установить Visual Studio для C++." - (перевод.)

Данная библиотека распознавания лиц, должна работать как можно шустрее, значит большая часть её кода на более быстром языке чем python (в разы), поэтому она написана на С++, но что бы собрать её под python, нужен компилятор С++, для Windows обычно используется компилятор от Microsoft, у вас как раз его и не хватает.

Решение:
Установи Visual Studio C++

Comment: Спасибо большое